# Setting parameter values in SQL for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters

E.g. I have a SELECT query Q with a text parameter named P. I would like to write something like this:

```
SET P = 'sometext'; SELECT * FROM Q;
```

Edit: Since it causes so much confusion, let's say Q is the following query in the Queries collection:

PARAMETERS P text;
SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeField = P;

(but note that P generally may appear anywhere parameters are allowed, it's just a simple example!)

Is it possible?

Edit2: Ok, I got it, not possible with Jet SQL, credits to @Rahul Tripath; @HansUp. Thanks to everyone who tried.

Edit3: I give an example for more clarity: Let's say table T contains time intervals when e.g. some servers are running. For example:

```
SERVER  | START      | END 
server1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-03
server1 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-01-20
server2 | 2021-01-18 | 2021-01-27
...
```

Now let's say query `Q` returns all servers that are running at a specific date `P`. So a user can ask with `Q`: Which servers were running on `2021-01-19`, for instance.

Now you have a second query `R` (the query above) which should return all servers that are running right now. So `R` could just select from `Q` by setting the parameter `P` to `NOW`.

Comment: MS Access does not support this syntax

Comment: What are you trying to do with `P`? Are you trying to update `Q` or filter `Q` with `P`?

Comment: @Brad: could be anything, the end user of Q doesn't need to know.

Comment: @IgorIvanov the difference is very important. It is not an end user question, it is a question for you.

Comment: @marc_s: why in hell did you edit my question and changed its meaning??

Comment: Sorry, Igor - I really don't understand *what* it should mean - it's very unclear.... I rolled back my attempts at making it clearer by editing it....

Comment: @Brad: I think due to marc_s's edit of my original question its meaning has been lost. Q is a SELECT query. edit: now it's back.

Comment: I think you're going to need to hold my hand some more. I'm still not clear on what you want to use `P` for. I'm confused because `P` does not appear in `SELECT * FROM Q` anywhere.

Comment: @Brad: **P is a parameter in Q**, as the question states. we have a multitude of various queries for different purposes, including, but not limited to, WHERE clauses. IOW P could be anywhere where Jet SQL rules allow a parameter to appear inside Q

Comment: For me it is absolutely clear what the author asks even before any edit has been made. I don't know how the author could have asked any clearer!? "What are you trying to do with P"? Well the author defined that very well: "It's a parameter in Q" (Read this again and again! It is not a parameter of the query here, but a parameter of Q!). Well and the second query shown here wants to set its value.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access supports [input parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as follow:

**[EDIT]**

If i understand you well...

```
PARAMETERS [cdate] DATE;
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT [UserId], [UserName], [CreationDate]
    FROM MyUsers
    WHERE [CreationDate] = [cdate]
) AS Q;
```

For further information, please see:
[Use parameters to ask for input when running a query](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN)
[Run a parameter query within an Access form](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/run-a-parameter-query-within-an-access-form/)

**[EDIT2]**

Finally, i think i got your point. You want to create dynamic query.
MS Access does not supports such as functionality directly in SQL code. To achieve that, you need to use VBA:

```
Dim par as String 
Dim sql as String

par = "whatever"
sql = "SELECT .... " & vbcr & _
    "FROM (" & vbcr & _
        "SELECT ..." & vbcr & _
        "FROM ..." & vbcr & _
        "WHERE [FilteredField] = " & par & vbcr & _
    ") AS Q;"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql
'or
'CurrentDb.Execute sql
```

Comment: That's how I write Q from my question, I want to call Q.

Comment: @IgorIvanov, i don't get you. `Q` is used as a name of table. Do you want to pass name of table as a parameter?

Comment: the confusion was due to the unwanted edit of my question. Now the original one is back.

Comment: Sorry @IgorIvanov, but your question is still unclear...

Comment: Using your example (let's call your query Q), how can I write
SET cdate = [some date value]; SELECT * FROM Q;

Comment: @IgorIvanov, please, see my answer now.... I hope i solved a riddle...

Comment: No; Q is in the Queries collection of the database. Now I want to say SET cdate = [some date value]; SELECT * FROM Q;

Comment: Do you want `Q` to be a dynamically called query? Is Q the actual variable you want to use and whatever it is you want to pass P into that?

Comment: @IgorIvanov, follow newly added links...

Comment: @maciej: I don't want to ask for input or use Access forms, I want to specify the parameter value in an SQL statement as I showed in my example!

Comment: Access SQL does not allow you to specify the parameter value within the SQL statement.